# [VBA control IE(html)]Select drop-list contents & automatically change error

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

-PLEASE SEE FIRST GIF file.

[GIF explaination][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwEed.gif

I am trying to make web automatically control macro using VBA. During making process, there were many block points. But I could solved it due to your help.

But there was big issue during script.

- explaination:

If I choose 3(Domain, Product design, Tech Center) datas, "Validator", "Manager" value is choosed automatically.

But there is no changes, as I choosed 3 datas. And then when I clicked using mouse, at that time "Validator", "Manager" value was changed.

Please tell me what is the problem or how can I improve.
Thank you in advance.

And if you need more information please tell me what you need.

```
Sub a()

Dim IE_ctrl As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim HTMLDoc As IHTMLDocument
Dim input_Data As IHTMLElement
Dim url As String
Dim I, J, JJ As Integer

J = 2

'URL Setting'
url = "https://apps.faurecia/sites/fcm_km_testing/Site%20pages/Homepage.aspx"

'Explorer Setting'
Set IE_ctrl = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE_ctrl.Silent = True
IE_ctrl.Visible = True
IE_ctrl.navigate url

Wait_Browser IE_ctrl

Set HTMLDoc = IE_ctrl.document

'Click - Create a new Test report'
For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
    Debug.Print input_Data.alt
    If input_Data.alt = "IcnCreate.png" Then
    input_Data.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next
'END'

Wait_Browser IE_ctrl

'Insert - Insert LTI number'
For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    Debug.Print input_Data.ID
    If input_Data.ID = "txtLTINumber" Then
    input_Data.Value = Cells(J, 1)
    End If
Next
'END'

Wait_Browser IE_ctrl

'Click - LTI loading click'
For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    Debug.Print input_Data.ID
    If input_Data.ID = "btnFindLTI" Then
    input_Data.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next
'END'

Wait_Browser IE_ctrl

For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.Value
    If input_Data.Value = "3702e9f0-6271-42ff-b5b2-04ef121b0f69" Then
    input_Data.Click
    input_Data.Selected = True
    Exit For
    End If
Next


For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.innerText
    If input_Data.innerText = Cells(J, 2) Then
'    input_Data.Click
    input_Data.Value = Cells(J, 2)
'    input_Data.Focus
    input_Data.Selected = True
'    input_Data.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next

    For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(1).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.innerText
    If input_Data.innerText = Cells(J, 3) Then
    input_Data.Focus
    input_Data.Selected = True
    input_Data.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(2).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.innerText
    If input_Data.innerText = Cells(J, 4) Then
    input_Data.Focus
    input_Data.Selected = True
    input_Data.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("sp-peoplepicker-topLevel customPeoplePicker")(3).getElementsByTagName("input")
    Debug.Print input_Data.className
    If input_Data.className = "sp-peoplepicker-editorInput" Then
    input_Data.Value = Cells(J, 5)
    Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    Debug.Print input_Data.ID
    If input_Data.ID = "btnSave" Then
    input_Data.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[Choose dropbox lsit][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLb91.png

[Validator - before click dropbox list][2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2CtW.png

[Validator - after click dropbox list][3]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs32j.png

Comment: It would be easier if this was reduced to a single problem (and later ask about any subsequent requirements). This looks like a proprietary site (or login based at the least) which will make it difficult/impossible for us to test. Either you can find a way for us to either 1) replicate the problem 2) understand the problem well enough, from the info in your question, to give useful suggestions. Understanding it well enough from the question means including the relevant html, explaining what you have researched etc....

Comment: Could you clarify the lines that start _If I choose 3_ ........and ends with _"Manager" value was changed._

Comment: Sorry my explanation is not enough.
if you see the GIF? it is more easy explain.

(1) 3 datas("Domain", "Product design", "Tech center" : see https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLb91.png) are chosen(using VBA) automatically.

(2) Originally after (1) process, 2 results("Validators", "Manager") will be changed automatically.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2CtW.png)

When I using mouse click, 2 results is changed.
BUT I using VBA, 2 results is not changed.

Is it ok for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the values of "Validator" and "Manager" don't change because the click function behind "Domain" was not been fired.

Please try to use `Click` when you set the value of `<select>` to make the script running in the background.

As I don't have access to the website, I can't make a full test. I can only guess the example code is like this, you can edit the code according to your actual situation:

```
Set doc = ieA.Document
Set selectElement = doc.getElementById("txtDomain")  'get "Domain" element
selectElement.Click
selectElement.selectedIndex = 3  'set the option value using index
```